# Why do I get message "Access to the path 'bootmgr' is denied " when trying to clear the contents of a directory

Tags: c#

Using Windows 10 Home (20H2) on HP Spectre

I am trying to use the following code to clear the contents of a directory

```
public int clearDirectory(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo targetDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach (FileInfo file in targetDir.GetFiles())
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in targetDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        dir.Delete(true);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The target directory is on a USB SanDisk which has in its root dir one directory (which has a number of subdirectories) which I created and the following SanDisk files

```
SanDiskMemoryZone_AppInstaller.apk
SanDiskMemoryZone_QuickStartGuide.pdf
```

I replaced the path to the USB drive with a path to a directory on my C drive and that worked fine.

How does the bootmgr get involved in this?

Comment: There is probably a hidden file or folder called bootmgr which you can't delete. Was this flash drive used as an installation disc at some point?

Comment: bootmgr is present on any bootable disk, contains the OS bootstrapping code.  Its file attributes includes Hidden and System to warn you not to delete it.  Improve the C# code by using DirectoryInfo.Attributes, avoids deleting the recycle bin and system restore points.  And FileInfo.Attributes, avoids deleting bootmgr etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can declare for each drive if it is bootable or not.
The bootable partition in Windows is a hidden drive called system partition (and that‘s also the reason why no error was shown when you tried to delete the C:-drive)

Your SAN-drive seems to be using a file system which has a hidden folder with ACL only for the system account.

That‘s why you get this error. You have no access right to delete the file/folder.

One solution:

- change your code s.t. It only selects files without a leading dot, like with regex: `^\.`

If this still doesn’t fix your error then you should try use an elevated process (with adminr rights) to tackle this.

REMARK: before you delete everything from a usb stick, it would be easier to just reformat  it then deleting every file.
Maybe look into [Diskpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) for this.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by

change your code s.t. It only selects files without a leading dot, like with regex: ^\.

Using diskpart I cleaned the drive so that all the space on the drive was unallocated. I then created a new volume with Disk Manager and recreated my directories on the USB drive. However, the problem remained. I still get the access denied to bootmgr message.

Comment: The problem, in the end lay, in the fact that somehow (I don't know how) the bootmgr file became part to one of the directories that I was trying to delete. On rebuilding the contents of the directories from scratch the problem went away.

Comment: Interesting. What file format system did you use? EXFAT? Or did the USB Stick came pre formatted?